# Move woocommerce category description below products in Astra theme

Tags: woocommerce, categories

Does anyone know how to do this on this theme (Astra)?

Thanks

I tried this code but the description appears both at the top and at the bottom:

```
// move category description to bottom of pages

remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description','woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );
```

Comment: This can be because your theme is already making related customizations… You need to ask in the theme authors support pages.